# How to send array of json objects to spring controller using ajax

Tags: json, ajax, spring-mvc

I have converted all tables into json format using the below code:

```
var table2 = $('#yTable').tableToJSON();          
alert(JSON.stringify(table2));
```

How do I send these three json arrays to spring controller? In spring controller I want these json array of objects as separate params:

```
    [
    {"Label":"A","Dimension":"0"},
    {"Label":"B","Dimension":"10"},
    {"Label":"C","Dimension":"20"},
    {"Label":"D","Dimension":"30"},
    {"Label":"E","Dimension":"40"}
    ]

    [
    {"Label":"1","Dimension":"0"},
    {"Label":"2","Dimension":"10"},
    {"Label":"3","Dimension":"20"},
    {"Label":"4","Dimension":"30"},
    {"Label":"5","Dimension":"40"}]



    [
    {"Label":"Floor1","Dimension":"0"},
    {"Label":"Floor2","Dimension":"10"},
    {"Label":"Floor3","Dimension":"20"},
    {"Label":"Floor4","Dimension":"30"},
    {"Label":"Floor5","Dimension":"40"}
    ]
```

**ajax call**

```
 $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
              contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
              dataType : 'json',
              url: "/bimspring/gridData",
              data: JSON.stringify(postData),
            success : function(response) {
               // do something ... 
            },
            error : function(e) {
               alert('Error: ' + e);
            }
        });
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/gridData", method = RequestMethod.POST)   
    public  @ResponseBody String  getSearchUserProfiles(@RequestBody Search[] list) {   
        return null;
       }
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions/ errors in console? Post your full code, containing the content of `postData`.

Comment: Is the problem is solved or not?